# Why django runs its own tests when doing ./manage.py test

Tags: django, unit-testing

In django 1.4. I have now created a few apps, each of them contains tests.py.

But when I do `./manage.py test`, django runs its own 412 tests, but I want to skip them all only run my test cases. How can I configure for this?

Comment: This doesn't happen anymore in Django 1.6!

Answer (score 1):

You can do `./manage.py test app_name` , where the `app_name` is the name of your application

See here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/testing/#running-tests

Comment: I got this, but can I simply use test command to run all my tests?

Comment: One thing you could do is to exclude the apps you don't want to test: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2211/